# Adding own HTML to doxygen CHM

Tags: html, vba, documentation, doxygen

I want to add additional Resources to the Documentation I created with doxygen. I added the needed HTML Files to the `HTML_EXTRA_FILES` and created a *.md file with the following code:

```
/*! \mainpage MY TITLE HERE
* \section intro_sec External resources
* <a href="link_to_my_external_page.html">My external page</a>
*/
```

When I run doxygen with the new file in the source folder a new page is then added to the documentation as expected, however the page itself does not contain any link?
I cant seem to find my mistake.
I am using vbfilter to create VB documentations with doxygen - could this be the culprit? How could I overcome this problem?

Comment: When I run the example file you give with the current doxygen version (1.8.14)  I see the link (though the input is not really a markdown file but a c / h file, for a markdown file remove the `/*`, `*` and `*/` comment signs. Which version of doxygen are you using? The vbfilter should not be the problem, but I'm not familiar with it. Just try first if you can see the the documentation from the "markdown" file.

Comment: I didn't see the `CHM` part but do you see the link in the "normal" HTML output?

Comment: hey I tried to remove the`/*`; `*` and `*/` in the md file but the problem remains. I see the page but it does not contain a link. I am using doxygen (1.8.14) as well. What exactly do yu mean with a/c file and how could I create one? thanks for your help!

Comment: So if I understand it correctly you don't see the link in the HTML output either. Please post the difference of your used Doxyfile compared to a standard / default Doxyfile.

Comment: Wit a c / h file I mean a regular C source or include file like aa.c / aa.h

Comment: correct - no link in the HTML Output either

Comment: Strange I created a small `link_to_my_external_page.html`  and set in my Doxyfile `HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = link_to_my_external_page.html` and generated with doxygen 1.8.14 and I see the link and when I click on it it works. Please  post the difference of your used Doxyfile compared to a standard / default Doxyfile. Also try it on a small project without the vbfilter.